# Syntax error on token "sList", VariableDeclaratorId expected after this token ..........? How to solve this issue..?

Tags: java

**Object Deserialization**
sList cannot be resolved to a type
how to solve this problem

```
public static ArrayList<Student> deSerialize(String filename) {
    ArrayList<Student> sList = new ArrayList<Student>();

    try {
        FileInputStream fiStream = new FileInputStream(filename);
        ObjectInputStream inStream = new ObjectInputStream(fiStream);

        @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
        sList = (ArrayList<Student>) inStream.readObject();
        fiStream.close();
        inStream.close();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println(e);
    }
    return sList;
}
```

[see the screenshot of the error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lyxwL.png)

Comment: I think you could also use try-with-resources on the two input streams.

Answer (score 1):

In Java you can't put annotations (`@...`) on random pieces of code.
Just move `@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")` above the method declaration:

```java
 @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
 public static ArrayList<Student> deSerialize(String filename) {
     ArrayList<Student> sList = new ArrayList<Student>();
     try {
         FileInputStream fiStream = new FileInputStream(filename);
         ObjectInputStream inStream = new ObjectInputStream(fiStream);
         
         sList = (ArrayList<Student>) inStream.readObject();
         fiStream.close();
         inStream.close();
     } catch (Exception e) {
         System.out.println(e);
     }
     return sList;
 }
```

To be precise, there is a limited number of places where you can put `@SuppressWarnings`, they are all listed in the [`@Target` annotation in the documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/SuppressWarnings.html).

For instance, because it’s a local variable **declaration**, you can − however − write:

```java
public static ArrayList<Student> deSerialize(String filename) {
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    ArrayList<Student> sList = new ArrayList<Student>();
}
```

In this case, it is useless, but legal.